# HTML table element is not working with their attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make contents DOM by Javascript.
so I created elements and appended to DOM.
Howerver, attribute is not applying to Table like border.
I could just see text.
also I tried to change attirube after appending. but not working[image]

```
  var iwContent = document.createElement("div");
  iwContent.className = 'infowindow';
  iwContent.setAttribute('style',"width:160px;text-align:center;padding:5px");
  
  var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
  var text = document.createTextNode("Hello");
 
  h3.appendChild(text);
  iwContent.appendChild(h3);

  var table = document.createElement("table");
  table.border = '1';
  table.style.textAlign = "center";
  //table.setAttribute('border', '1');
  //table.setAttribute('style',"border-collapse:collapse; text-align: center;");
  
  
  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let row = thead.insertRow();

  var th = document.createElement("td");

  var text1 = document.createTextNode("name");
  var text2 = document.createTextNode("manhole1");

  th.appendChild(text1);
  th.appendChild(text2);
  row.appendChild(th);

  iwContent.appendChild(row);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jaeseo Lee you have applied "border-collapse:collapse;"  this style to your table because of this your border is disappear, you have to remove this from code.
I've tried this code and works fine.

```
var iwContent = document.createElement("div");
iwContent.className = 'infowindow';
iwContent.setAttribute('style',"width:160px;text-align:center;padding:5px");

var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
var text = document.createTextNode("Hello");

h3.appendChild(text);
iwContent.appendChild(h3);

var table = document.createElement("table");
//table.border = '1';  //this is also working
table.width='50%';
table.height='50%';
table.style.textAlign = "center";
//table.setAttribute('border', '1');  //this is also working
table.setAttribute('style','border:1px solid blue; text-align:center;');


let thead = table.createTHead();
let row = thead.insertRow();
var th = document.createElement("th");

var text1 = document.createTextNode("name");
var text2 = document.createTextNode("manhole1");

th.appendChild(text1);
th.appendChild(text2);

row.appendChild(th);

iwContent.appendChild(row);
```